# Associating columns of data in MySQL with different values

Tags: mysql

I think this is an easy question but I can't quite wrap my head around the answer.  In one database table I have a series of location ID's that are associated with location ID's in another table.  I would like to create an explicit and unchanging link between these's ID's, but the ID's themselves have different values.

How would I make sure that an employee in (for example) BA789 or BA8001 is always associated with location code CN345 (they are the same physical location).

Thanks, Tom

Comment: What connection is there between these tables?  Remember, SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no such thing as a natural ordering in the table.

Comment: @tomish Learn about joins. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @Sam D don't joins require a column in each table to have the same data?

Comment: I could make the CN345 ID (and others like it) available in both tables, so then I guess it would be SELECT table2.BAID where table1.CNID = table2.CNID

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to SO. You should put more information on your question. Like your tables structure and some data example of each of then. Then you say what you need as a result. Of course, try to show some effort. We are not here to do it for you. Try and if it not work you put your attempt and we will be able to help you.

Comment: @JeffHawthorne yes Jeff if the data is not related in anyway then it defeats the purpose of a relational db. OP is not clear as what the db design actually is.  "location ID's that are associated with location ID's in another table" to me sounds like a relation

Comment: in my opinion, your best bet is to add the location code column to your employee table, make it a foreign key from the location table(if i understand your table structure correctly). if it is a foreign key, then you won't be able to accidentally assign an employee to a location that doesn't exist, and you can update the location code in the parent table and have it automatically update the code in the other table. 

you can do this without using a foreign key and just joining on the same column in each table, but you run the risk of losing data integrity.

Comment: @tomish Please consider to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20621638/edit) your question and add table schemas and some sample data for both tables to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your actual table schemas and sample data, but if your tables looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE locations
(
  location_id VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE employees
(
  employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  location_id VARCHAR(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations(location_id)
);
```

Then you can introduce many-to-many mapping table between location codes(ids)

```
CREATE TABLE location_map
(
  location_id1 VARCHAR(6), 
  location_id2 VARCHAR(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (location_id1) REFERENCES locations(location_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (location_id2) REFERENCES locations(location_id)
);
```

with the following contents

```
| LOCATION_ID1 | LOCATION_ID2 |
|--------------|--------------|
|        BA789 |        CN345 |
|       BA8001 |        CN345 |
```

Now you can do something like

```
SELECT employee_id, location_id, 
       COALESCE(m.location_id2, location_id) mapped_location_id
  FROM employees e LEFT JOIN location_map m
    ON e.location_id = m.location_id1;
```

Sample output:

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | LOCATION_ID | MAPPED_LOCATION_ID |
|-------------|-------------|--------------------|
|           1 |       BA789 |              CN345 |
|           2 |      BA8001 |              CN345 |
|           3 |      BA9999 |             BA9999 |
```

Comment: Terrific peterm!  thanks so much - I will try this implementation later this evening!  Tom

Comment: @tomish Great :) Let me know how did it go.